# 'xfdesktop' commands returning error in terminal

Tags: linux, archlinux, xfce, manjaro

When running a Python script to automatically change the background on my Xfce install of Manjaro Linux, occasionally the script will throw the following error:

> ** (xfdesktop:13267): CRITICAL **: 16:18:15.893: xfdesktop: already running, quitting.

I've narrowed down the cause of the error to the `xfdesktop --reload` command in the following line of the script:

`subprocess.Popen(['xfdesktop --reload'], shell=True)`

Running the same command outside of the script in a normal terminal gives the same behavior; it'll work a few times and then throw the above mentioned error. The error is also thrown for any other `xfdesktop` commands (except for `xfdesktop -V`)

Manually killing the `xfdesktop` process in `htop` allows the command to work several more times, but the error will inevitably be thrown again after a few minutes.

I am running Manjaro 18.0.2. Here's the output of `xfdesktop -V`:

```
This is xfdesktop version 4.13.2git-UNKNOWN, running on Xfce 4.13.
Built with GTK+ 3.24.2, linked with GTK+ 3.24.2.
Build options:
    Desktop Menu:        enabled
    Desktop Icons:       enabled
    Desktop File Icons:  enabled
```

Does anyone have any reason why `xfdesktop` is behaving this way and what I can do to stop it from throwing those errors?

Comment: I can reproduce this with 4.13.2, but not with 4.12.4. Very likely a bug/regression, please report at http://bugzilla.xfce.org.

Comment: If you use xfconf-query to change the background, xfdesktop is supposed to react automatically, no need to reload. Can you share your script?

Comment: @AndreLDM The script that changes the background can be found here: https://gitlab.com/bharadwaj-raju/WeatherDesk/blob/master/Desktop.py

As far as I can tell, this issue persists on 4.13.3.

Comment: the issue was [fixed](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15060) and will land soon in Xfdesktop 4.14.